# Mysql joins with left join and group by

Tags: mysql, left-join, inner-join

I want to combine three sql queries, Queries are given below,site and goods columns are common column,i want 9 columns in my result,if you run these three queries one by one,you will get 3 results having 3 columns,i want to combine these three results

```
select distinct
  a.site,a.goods,
  sum(a.quantity)
from
  stock_consumed a
group by
  a.site,a.goods


select distinct
  b.site,
  b.goods,sum(b.quantity)
from
  opening_balance b
group by
  b.site,b.goods


select distinct
  c.site,
  c.goods,sum(c.no_of_units)
from
  inward_stock c
group by
  c.site,c.goods
```

Comment: Those 3 queries will give 3 different results which are not related to each other. How do you plan to join them?

Comment: site column is common for all tables

Comment: May be site column is common. But you are grouping by site column in all the results. What I meant to say is, there is no relation between the **results** you are getting with these queries, not the actual table relation.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `union`. It allows you to combine the results of two queries as long as their results have the same number of columns.

```
select distinct a.site,a.goods,sum(a.quantity) from stock_consumed a group by a.site,a.goods
union 
select distinct b.site,b.goods,sum(b.quantity) from opening_balance b group by b.site,b.goods
union
select distinct c.site,c.goods,sum(c.no_of_units) from inward_stock c group by c.site,c.goods
```

Comment: it is giving three columns and three tables datas are mixed,i want nine columns

Comment: Sorry, but could you give please an example of the three queries output and what you want to achieve?

Comment: Please check this query,this is giving unmatched values ,select distinct a.site,a.goods,sum(a.quantity),b.site,b.goods,sum(b.quantity),c.site,c.goods,sum(c.no_of_units) from stock_consumed a left join opening_balance b on a.site=b.site left join inward_stock c on a.site=c.site group by a.site,a.goods

Comment: And what is not good with the query you provide? We do not have your data nor do we know the result you want to achieve. Please edit your question to provide a clear example.